# Anchor height controlled by div

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have the following html:

```
<div class='mydiv'>
   <div id="one">
      <a href='#'>Link</a>  
   </div>
   <div id="two">
   </div>  
<div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
div.mydiv {
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px;
  background-color:red; 
}

 div.mydiv a { 
   display:block;
   color:yellow;
   background-color:green;
   height:100%;
 }
```

This gives the following result:

[image: Image 1]

The green area is clickable. Is there anyway i can make it look like the following, only using CSS?

[image]

Comment: can you describe a lil more? do you want to remove red color?

Comment: No i would like to make the link for the entire area, not only for <div id="one">

Comment: check my answer if that's what you want

Comment: What does div id=2 do in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding-bottom:100%`

```
div.mydiv a { 
   display:block;
   color:yellow;
   background-color:green;
   height:100%;
   padding-bottom:100%;
 }
```

```css
div.mydiv {
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px;
  background-color:red; 
}

 div.mydiv a { 
   display:block;
   color:yellow;
   background-color:green;
   height:100%;
   padding-bottom:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class='mydiv'>
   <div id="one">
      <a href='#er'>Link</a>  
   </div>
   <div id="two">
   </div>  
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quiet understand what you are asking for, but if you want to make whole thing green then this would do the job:

*whole area is linked*

```css
div.mydiv {
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px;
  background-color:red; 
}
 div.mydiv a { 
   display:block;
   color:yellow;
   background-color:green;
   height:100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class='mydiv'>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <div id="one">
  </div>
  <div id="two">
  </div>  
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to also assign `height: 100%` to `#one` since the link is a child of `#one`

```css
div.mydiv {
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px;
  background-color:red; 
}

#one, div.mydiv a {
  height: 100%;
}

div.mydiv a { 
   display:block;
   color:yellow;
   background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class='mydiv'>
   <div id="one">
      <a href='#'>Link</a>  
   </div>
   <div id="two">
   </div>  
<div>
```